# C++ for each With a Pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, foreach, iterator

I am trying to use a pointer to an array inside of a for each loop in C++. The code below won't work because the "for each statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int *'". I'd prefer to use the new operator so that the array is on the heap and not the stack, but I just can't seem to figure out the syntax here. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int total = 0;

    int* array = new int[6];
    array[0] = 10; array[1] = 20; array[2] = 30;
    array[3] = 40; array[4] = 50; array[5] = 60;

    for each(int i in array) {
        total += i;
    }

    cout << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a `for each` statement in C++ ?

Comment: Ranged-based for in C++11, yes.

Comment: This is not the C++11 range-based for.  This is a Visual C++ extension.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I didn't know that. It kind of renders my answer pointless, then, if this is the desired syntax. >.>

Comment: @chris: Nevermind. I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: Hey, look what I found. My answer was actually the code restored to its former glory: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arich/archive/2004/09/08/227139.aspx. If the reason you killed the vector is so that it's on the heap, don't worry. Vectors allocate on the heap.

Comment: @OP Why not use one of the standard options (ordinary for-loop, or `std::for_each`, or the C++11 range-based for)?

Comment: @chris: Okay, so according to that it will work.  I had doubts because I thought it might only be for clr types. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says *"expression evaluates to a type that implements IEnumerable"*

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, A link on that page that I found interesting: [How to: Iterate over an STL collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177203(v=vs.80).aspx). I see where you're coming from, though.

Comment: Step back from the syntax, and think about how to do the job. You should really be using `std::accumulate` instead of a variation of a `for` loop (standard or otherwise).

Comment: `#define in :` and `#define foreach for` in C++11. Almost your syntax and still works. Not so good of an idea though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `for each` thing you are using is a Visual C++ extension that's not even recommended by some microsoft employees (I know I've heard [STL](http://nuwen.net/stl.html) say bad things about it, I can't remember where).

There are other options, like [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), and [range-based for](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#for) from C++11 (though I don't think Visual C++ supports that yet).  However, that's not what you should be using here.  You should be using [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), because this is the job that it was made for:

```
total = std::accumulate(array, array + 6, 0);
```

If you're really just interested in how to use this Microsoft `for each` construct, well, I'm pretty sure you can't if you just have a pointer.  You should use a `std::vector` instead.  You should be doing that anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Looks like I should get another compiler since I can't use the range-based for in Visual C++ 2010. The addition was actually just part of an example I found somewhere but the goal was just get the loop working. I see a lot of suggestions here to use `vector`, but I was just wondering how to make this work with an array. Is a `vector` usually recommended over an array?

Comment: @user1500832, There's rarely a case where an array is recommended over a vector (or std::array).

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know. I'm still fairly new to the language (good amount of C, but not so much Cpp) so I'm still learning what the best practices are.

Answer (score 2):

you can always use for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
{
total += array[i];
}
```

Although, answer for using "for each" using "gcnew" is already being given so I am omitting that. As an alternative, you can also use vectors as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int total = 0;
    vector<int> myarray;

    myarray.push_back(10);
    myarray.push_back(20);
    myarray.push_back(30);
    myarray.push_back(40);
    myarray.push_back(50);
    myarray.push_back(60);

    for each(int i in myarray) {
        total += i;
    }

    cout << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: The user is asking `foreach`. The solution you gave is beyond unnecessary here

Comment: Still it's a workaround. Let us let the OP decide whether it helped.

Answer (score 2):

C++0x introduced a ranged-based `for` loops, which work equal to `foreach` in other languages. The syntax for them is something like this:

```
int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
for( int & tmp : arr )
{
//do something
}
```

These loops work for C-style arrays, initializer lists, and any type that has begin() and end() functions defined for it that return iterators.
I strongly believe that `int *` doesn't have begin() and end() functions for them that return iterators, because it's just a raw pointer. I also believe that other `foreach`-equivalents such as `foreach` in Qt, or what you've posted, work the same way, so you can't use them like this. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says that it works for *collections*:

```
for each (type identifier in expression) {
      statements
}
```

> *expression:*
>
> A managed array expression or collection. The compiler must be able
>       to convert the collection element from Object to the identifier type. 
>       expression evaluates to a type that implements IEnumerable, IEnumerable, 
>       or a type that defines a GetEnumerator method. In the
>       latter case, GetEnumerator should either return a type that implements
>       IEnumerator or declares all the methods defined in IEnumerator.

Once again, you have a raw pointer, so it will not work.

Comment: Since you brought it up: It is actually possible to apply [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to C-style arrays.

Comment: @jogojapan, please read my answer more carefully. I did say it works for C arrays.

Comment: My remark is about this statement you made: _I strongly believe that `int *` doesn't have `begin()` and `end()` functions for them that return iterators_. Now I am no longer sure what exactly that means.

Comment: @jogojapan, I was trying to stress that there's a difference between `int arr[5]` and `int * arr = new int[5]`

Comment: Do C arrays really have a `begin()` and `end()`? Iss that another VC++ extension?

Comment: @steffen: They don't have members.  But C++11 introduces the functions, `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, which you can call on C-arrays or standard library containers (or anything with begin() and end() member functions)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think about is iterating over **array of reference types** especially if you want your storage on the heap

[Here Microsoft shows you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177204%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) how to do so

But for your case, the simplest alternative (if you want your array on the heap) would be as follows:-

```
 array<int>^ arr = gcnew array<int>{10, 20, 30, 40. 50, 60};
 int total = 0;    

for each (int i in arr){
  total+=i;
}
```

gcnew creates an instance of a managed type (reference or value type) on the garbage collected heap. The result of the evaluation of a gcnew expression is a handle (^) to the type being created.

Comment: `^`? Is VC++ officially a different language than C++?

Comment: @steffen, I like to think of it that way.

Comment: @steffen: No, it's not, (unless you count minor extensions like the for each construct).  However, the `^` thing is part of a very different language called C++/cli.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an standard library collection such as `std::vector` or `std::array`to use `for each`.

Please note that this codee I not standard C++, therefore not portable, because `for each` is a Visual C++ extension. I recommend to use `std::for_each` or C++11 auto ranged loops.

Answer (score 0):

VC++ is not different from ISO/ANSI C++. Anybody who tells you that it is, is wrong. Now, to answer your question of the for each statement. There is no such statement in the ISO C++ specification. Microsoft supports the 'foreach' statement in C#, as part of the .Net framework. As a result, there might be a chance that this is supported in Visual Studio, although I would recommend not using it.

Like the user shubhansh answered a few replies back, try using a vector. However, I'm guessing you would like to use a generic size, rather than hard-coding it in. The following for loop would help you in this regard:

```
    for(vector<int>::size_type i =0; i<myarray.size();i++)
{
total+=1;
}
```

This is the perfect way to iterate through a vector, as defined by the ISO standard.
Hope this helps you in your development.
Cheers!